# Cancel Magento Orders With Expired Pre-Authorization

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, authorize.net

I have some orders in my Magento site that are older than 30 days so the authorize.net pre-auth has expired. When I go to cancel the orders, it tries to submit the pre-auth void but it fails because the original transaction no longer exists. Is there any way to manual override this void procedure and simply cancel an order in this state?

Comment: Is this a custom authorize.net payment module or the default magento module?

Comment: These transactions were done with the built in Magento Auth.net API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look @

> /app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php

Turn on debugging for your payment module to see the result of `$result->getResponseCode()` for an expired transaction. Once you figure out what the result (code/error code) are, you could create a new 'case' that mimic `case self::RESPONSE_CODE_APPROVED:`

Also take a look @ $this->_isTransactionExpired($realAuthTransactionId) to see why it isn't catching your expired transaction.

```
protected function _voidCardTransaction($payment, $card)
{
    $authTransactionId = $card->getLastTransId();
    $authTransaction = $payment->getTransaction($authTransactionId);
    $realAuthTransactionId = $authTransaction->getAdditionalInformation($this->_realTransactionIdKey);

    $payment->setAnetTransType(self::REQUEST_TYPE_VOID);
    $payment->setXTransId($realAuthTransactionId);

    $request= $this->_buildRequest($payment);
    $result = $this->_postRequest($request);

    switch ($result->getResponseCode()) {
        case self::RESPONSE_CODE_APPROVED:
            if ($result->getResponseReasonCode() == self::RESPONSE_REASON_CODE_APPROVED) {
                $voidTransactionId = $result->getTransactionId() . '-void';
                $card->setLastTransId($voidTransactionId);
                return $this->_addTransaction(
                    $payment,
                    $voidTransactionId,
                    Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment_Transaction::TYPE_VOID,
                    array(
                        'is_transaction_closed' => 1,
                        'should_close_parent_transaction' => 1,
                        'parent_transaction_id' => $authTransactionId
                    ),
                    array($this->_realTransactionIdKey => $result->getTransactionId()),
                    Mage::helper('paygate')->getTransactionMessage(
                        $payment, self::REQUEST_TYPE_VOID, $result->getTransactionId(), $card
                    )
                );
            }
            $exceptionMessage = $this->_wrapGatewayError($result->getResponseReasonText());
            break;
        case self::RESPONSE_CODE_DECLINED:
        case self::RESPONSE_CODE_ERROR:
        if ($result->getResponseReasonCode() == self::RESPONSE_REASON_CODE_NOT_FOUND
            && $this->_isTransactionExpired($realAuthTransactionId)
        ) {
          .....


public function canVoid(Varien_Object $payment)
{
    if ($this->_isGatewayActionsLocked($this->getInfoInstance())) {
        return false;
    }
    return $this->_isPreauthorizeCapture($this->getInfoInstance());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do these Cancels as one-offs when you need to is to:

1) Grab the Auth.net transaction ID from the Order in Magento. It should display this in the Comments History at the bottom of the order.

2) Search the sales_payment_transaction table > txn_id field for that transaction ID

3) Once you locate the record in mySQL (helpful if you have phpMyAdmin), then just NULL out the txn_id for that record.

4) Back in Magento admin, you can now Cancel the order since it knows not to try and go back to Auth.net to cancel it.

** Alternatively you can easily find the record by the Order ID in the URL and find it that way in the same table. For instance:

```
https://www.yourdomain.com/store/index.php/backend/sales_order/view/order_id/6957/key/4c16ff2bfed4b496670be4747sdjhdfd6/
```

It's order_id: 6957 in the database.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for how to cancel an order with an expired authorization.
Update the database record for sales_payment_transaction by changing the is_cloased value for the transaction to 1(Yes).
You will need the order id and the transaction id which you can both get from the url when viewing the transaction in your browser.

https//magento.com/admin/sales_transactions/view/**txn_id/11111**/**order_id/55555**/

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment_transaction')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('order_id', '11111')
->addAttributeToFilter('txn_id', '55555');

foreach ($collection as $col) {
    if ($col->getId()){
        $col->setIsClosed(1)->save();
    }
}
```

You can also update the value through phpMyAdmin by opening the sales_payment_transaction and looking the for the row with order_id and txn_id for your order.

Once the is_closed value is set to 1, you should now be able to cancel the order since it tells the system the authorization is closed and not to try to void the authorization which has already expired on authorize dot net